# Promises in nodejs with Q save ref to mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

Need help with. Have a mongoose document which i build from api; i need to populate country field with reference from another mongoose query. Everything works fine expect i can access to my first document object in the function i use to retrieve second object

```
var instituteQelasy;
if (res) {
    instituteQelasy = res;
    instituteQelasy.name = object.name;
} else {
    instituteQelasy = new instituteModel({
        name: object.name,
        idQelasy: object.id
    });
}

if (typeof object.country.id !== 'undefined') {
    var country = new countryModel();
    var countryRef = country.findByIdQelasy(object.country.id, function(err, res) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }

        if (res) {
            deferred.resolve(res._id);
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    });

    countryRef(res).then(function(data) {
        instituteQelasy.country = data;
    });
}

instituteQelasy.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log('something went wrong while saving!');
});
```

EDIT: Since you guys point to intern mongoose. Here how my files look like
My country.js looks like and why i didn't use mongoose promises

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require('../config/config')[env];
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var countrySchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    idQelasy: {type: String, required: true},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, {collection: 'qel_par_country', versionKey: false});

countrySchema.methods.findByIdQelasy = function (id, callback) {
    return mongoose.model('Country').findOne().where('idQelasy').equals(id).exec(callback);
}

countrySchema.methods.findByName = function (name, callback) {
    return mongoose.model('Country').findOne().where('name').equals(name).exec(callback);
}

mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);
```

Then i import it to my server.js file like this

```
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models';
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function (file) {
    require(models_path + '/' + file);
});
var countryModel = mongoose.model('Country');
```

Comment: Doesn't mongoose already return promises? Just do `var countryRef = Q(country.findByIdQelasy(object.country.id))`

Comment: thanks for your feedback but got : { state: 'pending' }

Answer (score 1):

Bergi is on the right track that Mongoose can return promises. However, `findByIdQelasy` does not return a promise. You need to call `exec()` to get a promise.

```
Q(country.findByIdQelasy(object.country.id).exec()).then(function (res) {
    instituteQelasy.country = res._id;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer you right about mongoose promises. See my edit